# Datatable Export is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I am trying to export the table but somehow the export functionality is not working .

Here is my script :--

```
var editor; 
$(document).ready(function() {
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax: "http://localhost:8080//TestQuartz/json/agent.json",
    table: "#agents",
});
$('#agents').dataTable( {
    dom: "Tfrtip",
    ajax: "http://localhost:8080//TestQuartz/json/agent.json",
    tableTools: {
        sRowSelect: "os",
        sSwfPath: "../TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        aButtons: [
            { sExtends: "editor_create", editor: editor },
            { sExtends: "editor_edit",   editor: editor },
            { sExtends: "editor_remove", editor: editor },
            {
                sExtends: "collection",
                sButtonText: "Save",
                sButtonClass: "save-collection",
                aButtons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'xls', 'pdf' ]
            },
            'print'
        ]
    }
} );
} ); 
</script>
```

I keep getting below error :-- 
 Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a function

I am able to built the table but the moment I am adding the export functionality it fails.
I am trying to integrate the export functionality in the sb-admin table.
I have included all the required JS files.

Any hep would be great.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix the issue . Was calling the script and JS wrongly.

```
<script>   
var editor; 

$(document).ready(function() {
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    ajax: "../json/agent.json",
    table: "#agents",

} );

$('#agents').dataTable( {
    dom: "Tfrtip",
    ajax: "../json/agent.json",
    "scrollX": true,
    "ordering": false,
    tableTools: {
        sRowSelect: "os",
        sSwfPath: "../TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        aButtons: [
            {
                sExtends: "collection",
                sButtonText: "Save",                               
                sButtonClass: "save-collection",
                aButtons: [ 'copy', 'xls', 'pdf' ]
            }

        ]
    }
} );
} ); 
</script>
```